# Remove file names using Powershell and RegEx, end up with similar file names

Tags: regex, powershell

I have created the following PowerShell script. I only got the issue now that sometimes I end up with similar files names which gives an issue. Below is the PS script.

```
[char[]]$replace = "^+%?:~*},<„”{=';>!|#@"
$regex = ($replace | % {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
  
Get-ChildItem -recurse -file |
  ForEach {
    if ($_.Name -match $RegEx){
      Ren $_.Fullname -NewName $($_.Name -replace $RegEx, '') -whatif
    }
  }



Example files:

Example file#
Example file+
Example file@
```

I was thinking about adding -1, -2 after those file names.

```
Expected outcome:

Example file
Example file-1
Example file-2
```

Comment: You examples are not clear. Please do add what is the input and what output are you expecting

Comment: as Mandy8055 pointed out, you need better examples. [*grin*] two or three original and the desired result for each. also  ... PLEASE wrap them in code formatting so that they are easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below regex:

```
.<\.your_file_extension_name>$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`.`** - Matches any character exactly one time.
- **`$`** - Matches end of line.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/KROBYi/4)

**Proposed Procedure:**

```
1. Initialize the counter to 0.
1. Filter out all the "example files" which you want to replace.
2. Get only the file name excluding the extension. // This step in missing from the solution. Therefore; used file-extension in the replacement part too.
3. for every filtered result:
      3.1. Use regex .$ to point to the last punctuation.
      3.2. Replace the punctuation matched by above regex with "-" + counterValue + ".txt". This can be optimized if step 2 is handled properly.
      3.3. Increment the counter.
4. End of loop thereby getting all file-names replaced accordingly.
```

**Powershell Command:**

```
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop\Where\Files\Are\Present> $counter = 0
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop\Where\Files\Are\Present> Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter example* | Foreach-Object {
>>   $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ( $_.Name -Replace '.\.txt', "-$counter.txt" )
>>   $counter++
>> }
```

**NOTES:**

1. For the above example; I used `.txt` as the extension of the files.
2. For getting only file names instead of extensions, please use [`[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension)